# gwt plugin cant find user-jar

Tags: gwt

I have Eclipse Helios and have downloaded and installed the GWT plugin.  If I go through the menu system I can arrive at GWT Desiogner so I assume the plugin has loaded.   However when I click on Model then GWT Java Project I am asked to configure GWT.  When I give the path to the installation directory it reports that gwt-user.jar cant be found.   So I have searched my entire disk and it is not there.   Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go and download GWT SDK from http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/download.html, unzip and you'll find gwt-user.jar there. Configure eclipse for GWT SDK and point to this unzipped folder.